# partition of an array with max difference of k

Tags: c, algorithm, np

I have an array of integer elements. I want to divide array in 2 sub-array such that the sum difference of sub-arrays is not more that K. and sub-array has maximum sum.

You can leave some elements also. means this is not compulsory that all elements must present in both sub-arrays. you can leave some elements too.

I thought dynamic programming can solve this problem But I am stuck.

Please suggest me some approach

Comment: Can you please show us what you have (your code)? Or are you asking for an algorightm?

Comment: I am asking an algorithm how I can approach

Comment: @ElKamina http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15650

Comment: @mch I did not know. A ridiculous rule, but a rule nevertheless! Thanks.